# Redux Dom Not refreshing

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am updating my redux state, and the state doesn't seem to be getting mutated, however the DOM is still not refreshing.

```
//update filters for events
setFilters = (name) => async () => {
const {onSetActiveEventTypes, authUser} = this.props;

let array = this.props.activeEventTypes
let index = array.indexOf(name);

if (index > -1) {
  array.splice(index, 1);
}else {
  array.push(name)
}

await Promise.resolve(onSetActiveEventTypes(array));
}


render() {
return <Accordion title="Filters" collapsed>
      {
        (this.props.eventTypes && this.props.activeEventTypes ?
          <EventFilter eventTypes={this.props.eventTypes} activeEventTypes={this.props.activeEventTypes} action={this.setFilters}/>
         : '')
      }
    </Accordion>
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
eventTypes: state.eventsState.eventTypes,
activeEventTypes: state.eventsState.activeEventTypes
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
onSetEventTypes: (eventTypes) => dispatch({ type: 'EVENT_TYPES_SET', 
eventTypes }),
onSetActiveEventTypes: (activeEventTypes) => dispatch({ type: 
'ACTIVE_EVENT_TYPES_SET', activeEventTypes })
});

const authCondition = (authUser) => !!authUser;

export default compose(
withAuthorization(authCondition),
connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
)(DashboardPage);
```

I have placed my code in my component above, it should be all that is needed to debug. I will put the reducer below

```
const applySetEventTypes = (state, action) => ({
...state,
eventTypes: action.eventTypes
});

const applySetActiveEventTypes = (state, action) => ({
...state,
activeEventTypes: action.activeEventTypes
});

function eventsReducer(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
switch(action.type) {
case 'EVENT_TYPES_SET' : {
  return applySetEventTypes(state, action);
}
case 'ACTIVE_EVENT_TYPES_SET' : {
  return applySetActiveEventTypes(state, action);
}
default : return state;
}
}

export default eventsReducer;
```

Above is my reducer, I think I am following the correct patterns for managing redux state and maintaining immutability. What am I missing?

setFilters is a method that the checkboxes use to update active filters compared to all the filters available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are **definitely** mutating state:

```
const {onSetActiveEventTypes, authUser} = this.props;

let array = this.props.activeEventTypes
let index = array.indexOf(name);

if (index > -1) {
  array.splice(index, 1);
}else {
  array.push(name)
}
```

That mutates the existing array you got from the state, and then you are dispatching an action that puts the *same* array back into the state.  So, you are both A) reusing the same array all the time, and B) mutating that array every time.

The approaches described in the [Immutable Update Patterns](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns) page in the Redux docs apply wherever you are creating new state values, whether you're generating the new state in a reducer based on a couple small values, or before you dispatch the action.

Comment: As I said, see the [Immutable Update Patterns](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns) page for examples.  In this case, you'd want to use `array.filter()` or `array.concat()` to generate the new array, and then dispatch the action containing the new array.

Answer (score 0):

```
//update filters for events
setFilters = (name) => async () => {
const {onSetActiveEventTypes, authUser} = this.props;

let array = []
this.props.activeEventTypes.map((type) =>{
  array.push(type)
})

let index = array.indexOf(name);

if (index > -1) {
  array.splice(index, 1);
}else {
  array.push(name)
}

//use this once server sending active filters
// await eventTable.oncePostActiveEventTypes(authUser.email, array).then( data 
=> {
//   Promise.resolve(onSetActiveEventTypes(data));
// })
await Promise.resolve(onSetActiveEventTypes(array));
}
```